# время выполнения програмы

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте! Помогите разобраться в проблеме. Есть две программы реализующие алгоритм AES: одна написана на языке C#,другая на языке С. Прога которая написана на языке С выполняет процесс зашифрования файла размером 30мб за 10 секунд, а программа написанная на языке C# зашифровывает этот же файл за 2 часа. Почему такая разница по времени при обработке одного и того же файла, причем обе программы выполняются на CPU. Может ли быть причина в том как написана программа или дело в используемом языке программирования.

Comment: Скорее всего, на C# вы где-то "doing it wrong". Я работал с AES на C# и такое время - это откровенный перебор. Должно в районе тех же 10 секунд.

Comment: Профайлером прошлись по `C#` варианту?

Answer (score 7):

скорее всего в том как программа написана... уж больно большая разница.

Comment: Только надо не забывать, что именно язык подталкивает к использованию конкретных способов программирования того же самого алгоритма. 

Особенно, если доступные библиотеки позволяют компактно написать код.

Comment: А на шарпе, насколько я помню, есть из фреймворка функция кодирования/декодирование AES. И я вот сильно сомневаюсь что оно было использовано...